Is philosophy science or humanities?
Is philosophy a branch of science, a branch of the humanities, both, or neither? Personally, I think philosophy is neither a branch of science nor a branch of the humanities, it is in its own category. But I would love to read what philosophers have written about this topic.

Philosophy is the stump of science! It's what's left on this side of campus after all the branches of science left and planted themselves on the other side of campus, so that makes it the stump.

@gs. It's no so much whether philosophy belongs under sciences or humanities so much as which sub field of philosophy do humanities and sciences belong to

Leaving this as a comment since there are already many good answers but @Rushi  hit it on the head: science is basically a type of philosophy -- empiricism. The desiere to categorise fields of study under "science" or "humanities" is not a problem of categories, it is a problem of school administration: weather philosophy teachers work for the School of Science or School of Engineering or School of Humanities of School of Medicine etc..

Tnx @slebetman. I would put it that empiricism + rationalism fan out into science; ethics + aesthetics into the humanities. As to school administration HaHa! Bullseye! That also exposes how absurdly anachronistic the question (and most answers) are: What is Abe Lincolns twitter handle? Which spell checker does Shakespeare use? Where did Plato get his PhD?

Call for clarification: Do you think that Humanities is not a science? Or do you rather want to ask "Is philosophy an empirical or an analytical science?"

Science is a branch  of philosophy.

I don't understand what "is" means in the question. Does philosophy "exist" independently of humans? Can we in any way measure its relationship to "science" or "humanities"? What consequences would it have if it were "science", as opposed to "humanities"?

Neitehr; but if we have to choose between the "two boxes" (like in a US campus) it is clear that "Humanities" il less wrong.

Whoever said there was a choice, or that the choice was anything like black-and-white?

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanities philosophy is generally considered to belong to humanities and not to science.
Each demarcation of this type is to a certain degree arbitrary.
In the present case one can argue that science deals with all objects which are not made by humans. While philosophy deals with questions and answers which have been invented by humans and often investigate ideas and institutions established by them.
A different criterion to discriminate between philosophy and  science results from the different methods of research which both disciplines apply. Science observes, makes hypotheses and confirms or refutes the hypotheses by observation. Hence scientists should think about how to check their theories. As a consequence the idea of scientific progress is fundamental.
All these methods are not applied and are often not even applicable in philosophy. As a consequence, there is much less agreement in philosophy than in science. Sometimes, the idea of philosophical progress is explicitly denied by philosophers.

Where does engineering fit in this world view? Can philosophy invent a smartphone?

@DDuck Engineering at its best is applied science.

Re: "science deals with all objects which are not made by humans". So studying the stability of caves is science, but studying the stability of tunnels is engineering? When do plants start being "made by humans"? At genetical engineering, or already at selecting and breeding? What about computer science?

@IgorF. Engineering at its best is applied science. Hence genetical engineering, selective breeding and building tunnels is applied science. - I consider computer science a discipline which spans theoretical informatics and engineering.

Science was originally called natural philosophy. For Greek, Roman and pre-Enlightenment philosophers, there was no conceptual difference between speculation about the physical makeup of the universe and speculation about religion, souls or ethics.
One of the great advances of the Enlightenment was to separate science from philosophy, by giving an improved theory of study which produced the scientific method. Speculation about religion and souls can only ever be speculation, because faith by definition exists in the absence of proof. Different philosophers can legitimately come up with different conceptions of what exists here, in the absence of proof, and with different starting conditions or different lines of reasoning. Similarly different concepts of ethics can legitimately exist depending on the preconditions of what you consider to be morally right (or useful).
However we can assume that the physical world exists regardless of the faith or beliefs of humans. The advance of the scientific method was to make this assumption, and to cross-check theoretical concepts against observed reality. Many conclusions on the behaviour of the physical world by highly-respected philosophers such as Aristotle were found to be incorrect, and had to be replaced by models which gave a better fit to observed reality. Some schools of philosophy considered that this assumption cannot be made (and still do); and this is the core reason why science has grown away from philosophy.
The same process has also given us better ways of doing philosophy. In the case of medical ethics, for example, observed reality for what can go wrong and the frequency with which it goes wrong has given us a better model of informed consent. It has also given us a better understanding of where seeking consent from an individual is actively harmful for everyone else - for example with vaccination, where a  certain level of vaccinated population is required to prevent outbreaks of infectious diseases. These fields are generally considered to be "humanities".
So philosophy isn't really a "branch" of science. It's an old, gnarled apple tree that no longer produces much fruit, which is supplanted by two more vigorous younger trees with more abundant fruit that it seeded.

"the physical world exists regardless of the faith or beliefs of humans." -- although I personally believe that this is so, not all philosophers do.  Or that we can know whether it is so.

@JohnBollinger And that's why the scientific method needed to move science away from philosophy. :) I'll update the answer to make this more explicit though.

Probably depends on the time, the place and the sub-domain of philosophy.
Apparently the medieval canon of academic disciplines often just included: medicine, theology, legal systems and some "misc" category usually referred to as Arts or Philosophy for those not studying anything useful but bothering themselves with questions just for the sake of it, you know for the love of wisdom or how the Greek might have said: philosophy.
Apparently for that reason lots of disciplines still call their researcher grade degree PhD (or doctor of philosophy).
So in a sense "science" is usually a specialized branch of philosophy. So g s pretty much hits the nail on the head saying that what is left with philosophy is basically the stump of all the things that were philosophy after they moved to their own special department.
In German there's also a distinction in Naturwissenschaften (natural sciences) and Geisteswissenschaften (science of the mind), as the word "Wissenschaft" could be read as "generate wisdom". So in that context they would still be counted as "science" just a different field.
Now humanities apparently meant a distinction between the earthly (philosophy) and the divine (theology), so yeah it probably still fits there, as would the other sciences if they would have obliterated that system of distinction.
Now some domains of philosophy certainly bother with questions concerning the human experience others don't so whether they fit is probably a matter of time and space and how people constructing the campuses and organized their peer groups think of that.

Science is a branch of philosophy. Both science and philosophy study our world, but science is doing it using scientific method, while philosophy is not restricted to it. Scientific method is itself developed as a part of philosophic research.

Philosophy is not readily categorisable according to this, from Heidegger's What Is a Thing (1935), part 1, pages 2–4:

a little story is handed down which Plato has preserved in the
Theaetetus (174 a.f.): "The story is that Thales, while occupied in
studying the heavens above and looking up, fell into a well. A
good-looking and whimsical maid from Thrace laughed at him and told
him that while he might passionately want to know all things in the
universe, the things in front of his very nose and feet were unseen by
him." Plato added to this story the remark: "This jest also fits all
those who become involved in philosophy." Therefore, the question
"What is a thing?" must always be rated as one which causes housemaids
to laugh. And genuine housemaids must have something to laugh about.
Through the attempt to determine the question of the thing we have
unintentionally arrived at a suggestion about the characteristic of
philosophy which poses that question. Philosophy, then, is that
thinking with which one can start nothing and about which housemaids
necessarily laugh. Such a definition of philosophy is not a mere joke
but is something to think over. We shall do well to remember
occasionally that by our strolling we can fall into a well whereby we
may not reach ground for quite some time.
There remains the question as to why we talk about the fundamental
questions of metaphysics. The term "metaphysics" here should indicate
only that the questions dealt with stand at the core and center of
philosophy. However, by "metaphysics" we do not mean a special field
or branch within philosophy in contrast to logic and ethics. There are
no fields in philosophy because philosophy itself is not a field.
Something like a division of labor is senseless in philosophy;
scholastic learning is to a certain extent indispensable to it but is
never its essence. We therefore want to keep the term metaphysics free
from all that historically adheres to it. For us it signifies only
that procedure during which one runs the danger of falling into a
well.


First, philosophy covers two main branches: physics (experience, measurable facts, perception by the senses), and metaphysics (ideas, subjective facts, reason).
Science deals exclusively with physical phenomena. Science is said to seek for empirical truth. Metaphysical facts can't be addressed by the scientific method.
Humanities deal exclusively with a portion of metaphysics, which is related to human society and culture.
So, philosophy includes both, but it is neither one or the other.

You're being misled by the word metaphysics which is an anachronism and malapropism. Aristotle, who is considered the founders of metaphysics, neither used nor even knew the word

@Rushi Never said Aristotle (who is not the "founders" of metaphysics) used or knew the word. Not only metaphysics is difficult to precise, but all fields of knowledge. However, philosophy applies conventions. The term metaphysics is one of them.
